# Confusing reduction transformation

Tags: syntactic-analysis, appositives

Let's assume sentence below **(which is From "The Official Cambridge Guide to IELTS")**.

> Ants simply sense changes in their environment, as for example when the mound's wall has been damaged, altering the circulation of air.

By syntactic analysis of the sentence above we realize that the sentence is complete by reaching the word 'environment' therefore comma indicates an appositive. after the second comma we have an ING form of the verb which means a reduction transformation is occurred.
as far as I know in syntactical analysis if an ING form of the verb appeared after punctuations reduction has occurred and it should be reconstructed using (While + NP + To be) so that NP is reconstructed from the independent clause.

In other words, by reconstructing the sentence we have:

> Ants simply sense changes in their environment, as for example when the mound's wall has been damaged, **while ants are** altering the circulation of air.

But it doesn't make sense.
Meanwhile, appositive with comma construction cannot contains a full sentence. therefore, we cannot reconstruct the last sentence from the appositive.

what is the correct reconstruction of this sentence?

I would be so much appreciate that if some body explain that.

Comment: It’s not “while ants are” it’s “thus”.

Comment: Yes we can realize by the sentence meaning. But if we want to reconstruct the sentence based on syntactic analysis. the sentence should be completed using a subject and to be.
'while ants are'
'while the mound's wall is'
are the reconstruction possibilities however the second one doesn't make sense due to appositives and the first one is also meaningless. @Jim

Comment: It’s passive. The agent doing the damaging and thus the altering is not named.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I couldn't understand your answer. what do you mean by that? based on syntactical analysis can you mention what is the part of speech of altering?
actually who is altering? the mound's wall or the ants or the environment
By reconstructing that sentence it will become a relative clause therefor sentence formula wouldn't be incomplete. @Jim

Comment: I read the original as the equivalent of *Ants simply sense changes in their environment, as for example when the mound's wall has been damaged, which alters the circulation of air*.

Comment: The sentence does not require rewriting, or "reconstruction".  when the mound's wall has been damaged, altering the circulation of air. is the same as: when the mound's wall has been damaged and alters the circulation air. The use of ING as in this example often is a substitute for another tensed verb. He ran down the stairs, shouting as he ran. = He ran down the stairs and shouted as he ran. **There is no appositive in your sentence**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, The first sentence structure is (NP1 VP NP2 PP) which is a full sentence therefore comma is an appositive. even if we don't consider these thing the clause after 'environment' can be omitted without any change in meaning that's why I feel there should be at least one appositive in the sentence.

However on your answer you considered the second comma as an 'and'. since we don't have any 'and' or 'or' in the rest of the sentence I don't think that would be correct.
Actually I've never heard of such that comma. @Lambie

Comment: The 'rules' surrounding punctuation of parentheticals etc are far from rigorous, in spite of what textbooks etc may claim. I'd interpret << Ants simply sense changes in their environment, as for example when the mound's wall has been damaged, altering the circulation of air. >> to default to << Ants simply sense changes in their environment, as happens for example when the circulation of the air is altered as a result of damage happening to the mound's wall. >>

Comment: Also The sentence you mentioned in your answer can easily be reconstructed by the same rule. He ran down the stairs, while he was shouting as he ran.
after comma is appositive and also the sentence is meaningful. @Lambie

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I'm learning syntactical analysis because it has been said that this grammar (T-Grammar) does not have any exception which could really help me understand any sentence without ambiguity.
that's why i'm trying to learn this grammar. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: There is no apposition in your original sentence. This is your structure: He insisted there was apposition, arguing about it over several posts.

Comment: The trouble is that few even proficient Anglophones have even heard of T-bar grammar and so few use the language in the way it might demand. One can end up with a precisionist variant that doesn't explain how people actually speak and write. And ELU looks mainly at standard usage (pointing out perhaps where a certain grammar gives a non-standard usage). Here, I'm happy with the << 'Ants simply sense changes in their environment  –  as for example when the mound's wall has been damaged, altering the circulation of air.' >> analysis

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I'm not insisting on anything. the only thing I'm trying to do is to clarify misunderstandings. But your answer was not detailed. Lets consider there is no appositive in the sentence would you please explain part of speech of every single word (even commas)? 
If we don't have any appositive then why those commas out there?
these are the thing that I can't grasp if we don't consider commas as an appositive.
Again I appreciate you for your response. @Lambie

Comment: The commas in the original sentence **should be**: Ants simply sense changes in their environment **as, for example, when** the mound's wall has been damaged, altering the circulation of air.

Comment: The sentence in the question is from "The Official Cambridge Guide to IELTS". that's why I think the sentence along with punctuations should be correct.
here is a link to the full essay: [link](https://www.dol.vn/luyen-thi-ielts/ielts-online-test-official-cambridge-guide-to-ielts-test-3-reading-questions-answer-key-de-bai-dap-an-giai-thich-chi-tiet-free-pdf-download) @Lambie

Comment: No, it isn't an official guide. It's a **repost** by a Vietnamese person who may very well have made a mistake in reposting it.

Comment: Dear Lambie I also have the paper book. the sentence in the book was exactly the same as the one which was on that post. I can send you another link to official guide with the exact same punctuations. @Lambie

Comment: You are incorrectly using the term *appositive*. What you have after *environment* is a nonessential (nonrestrictive) element that can be left off without harming the sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention. yes you are right. however my main question was what is the correct reconstruction of the sentence (In T-Grammar). In other words who is exactly the subject of the last verb phrase without semantic analysis (only based on grammar) it can be "ants" or "environment" or "the mound's wall". that was the only reason which I wanted to reconstruct sentence based on T-Grammar. @TinfoilHat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ants simply sense changes in their environment, as for example when the mound's wall has been damaged, altering the circulation of air.

1. Ants simply sense changes in their environment = main clause
2. as for example when the mound's wall has been damaged = relative clause introduced by **as when**
3. altering the circulation of aid = verb phrase used instead of tensed verb.

**For example**: The battle continued for several hours, altering the course of the war.
**Compared to**: The battle continued for several hours and altered the course of the war.

ING can feel "more emphatic" or more active than using a tensed verb.

I have used a simple explanation and not the long-winded ones *associated with more academic interpretations.*

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer. But can we use comma as a conjunction instead of and in a written context especially an IELTS article which all the punctuations should be correct?
please accept my apology in asking too many questions but this would be a great help to those who trying to learn some grammars deeply. especially punctuations.

Comment: Commas are a matter of choice, usually. There are several ways to place them here. I have now put back your original comma in the sentence. To answer your question: a comma cannot "replace" a conjunction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and I marked your answer as a correct answer. However I couldn't understand what just happened. Because In your answer you pointed to an example which comma is replaced with an "and" conjunction while in your previous comment you mentioned we cannot replace comma with a conjunction.
Also in your analysis of sentence how can I understand who is the subject of the verb phrase (which you mentioned used as a tensed verb [last part]) actually I mean how can we specify the subject of that clause without semantic interpretation.

Comment: It's not a "replacement"; it's a rewrite. altering the circulation of aid=a verb phrase; and alter**ed** the etc.=a tensed verb.